# Add an image in a specific position in the Word document through R quarto

Tags: r, docx, quarto, officer

I am working on a script (`r.qmd`) that outputs into a Word document. I was hopping to place an image before my title.
I'll show an example below:

[image: word_example]

(Note that the location is before the main text, it is placed outside the main text margins).

Problem is, I have no idea and can't seem to find a way to code this. Meaning finding a way to specify x and y coordinates of the Word page to place the image in.

I am aware that `body_add_img` allows to insert images, but the only location specifications it has are:

> pos:  where to add the new element relative to the cursor, one of
> "after", "before", "on".